# Specifying number of indexes in AWS Elastic Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search and when I went through the documentation for AWS Elastic Search, I noticed that there is no where, where I can mention the number of shards per index or the number of indexes I require for my cluster in the cloud formation template. Are they using a different terminology for the same?

Answer (score 1):

AWS ES is managed by AWS, hence you cannot specify the default sharding strategy on the whole cluster, thus no option/mention of it in CloudFormation.

However, as a workaround for it you can:

- [create index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-template.html) which contain an index pattern that matches the nomenclature of your indices. Here you can specify the settings for all indices that match the index pattern.

  ```html
  PUT _index_template/2p_0r_index_template
  {
    "index_patterns" : ["logstash-*", "filebeat-*", "test-log-index*"],
    "template": {
      "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 2,
        "number_of_replicas": 0
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- [specify the sharding strategy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#create-index-settings) (primary and replica shard) whenever creating an index.

  ```html
  PUT index-000001
  {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 2,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  }
  ```